# How to pass value as a parameter from one method to another method

Tags: java, android, function, android-studio, parameters

I want to pass value of `arraylist(myList)` to the `addItemToSheet` function which is called inside `addView()` methond, the `arraylist(myList)` value is assigned inside first sniper. I don't understand how can I achieve this.

I am selecting the party detail in first sniper and inside `addview` method I am selecting the item details after that I want to store these both details party plus item details in database for that I have to pass all the data which I'm not able to pass party data as parameter to the `addItemToSheet` method which is calling inside `addView`.

```
public class selectparty extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView address,state,mobile,email,gstin,c_blnc;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private Button btnaddGSheet,btnaddItem;
    private LinearLayout listViewLayout;

    ArrayList<String> itemlist ;
     XlsxCon2 xlsxCon2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selectparty);
        address=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.addressid);
        state=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.stateid);
        mobile=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mobid);
        email=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.emailid);
        gstin=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.gstin);
        c_blnc=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cblnc_id);
//        resulttext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.resulttext);
        listViewLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listviewlayout_id);

        btnaddItem=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);

        btnaddGSheet=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnid);

        spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.searchableSpinner);
        final XlsxCon database = new XlsxCon(this);
        xlsxCon2 = new XlsxCon2(this);


        ArrayList<String> numberlist=database.getAllEmployee();
       itemlist=xlsxCon2.getAllEmployee();


        btnaddItem.setOnClickListener(this);


        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(selectparty.this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,numberlist));
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "plz select number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    resulttext.setText(" ");
                }
                else {

                    String snumber= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
//                    resulttext.setText(snumber);
                    **final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList=database.getSelectedEmp(snumber);**
                    address.setText( myList.get(0).get(Constant.LedgerAddress));
                    state.setText( myList.get(0).get(Constant.LedgerState));
                    mobile.setText( myList.get(0).get(Constant.LedgerMobile));
                    email.setText( myList.get(0).get(Constant.LedgerEmail));
                    gstin.setText( myList.get(0).get(Constant.LedgerGSTIN));

                    c_blnc.setText( myList.get(0).get(Constant.LedgerClosing));

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        addView();

    }

    private void   addItemToSheet(String USER_NAME,String Party,String Address,String State,String GSTIN, String Mobile, String EMAIL,String Closing_Balance,String ITEM,String GST,String CESS,String HSN,String SALE_RATE, String PUR_RATE,String QTY,String AMT,String GST_AMT,String CESS_AMT,String TOTAL) {

        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Adding Item","Please wait");
//        final String name = editTextItemName.getText().toString().trim();
        final String USER_NAMES = USER_NAME;
        final String PartyS = Party;
        final String AddressS = Address;
        final String StateS = State;
        final String GSTINS = GSTIN;
        final String MobileS = Mobile;
        final String EMAILS = EMAIL;
        final String Closing_BalanceS = Closing_Balance;
        final String ITEMS = ITEM;
        final String GSTS = GST;
        final String CESSS = CESS;
        final String HSNS = HSN;
        final String SALE_RATES = SALE_RATE;
        final String PUR_RATES = PUR_RATE;
        final String QTYS = QTY;
        final String AMTS = AMT;
        final String GST_AMTS = GST_AMT;
        final String CESS_AMTS = CESS_AMT;
        final String TOTALS = TOTAL;


//        final String brand = brands;




        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxEI2Zua_79qLkUpMSpfyFjNEshYti8wPD34ZFrmsy45tLGJbE/exec",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        loading.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(selectparty.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> parmas = new HashMap<>();
                //here we pass params
                parmas.put("action","addItem");
//                parmas.put("itemName",name);
//                parmas.put("brand",brand);
//
                parmas.put("USER_NAME",USER_NAMES);
                parmas.put("Party",PartyS);
                parmas.put("Address",AddressS);
                parmas.put("State",StateS);
                parmas.put("GSTIN",GSTINS);
                parmas.put("Mobile",MobileS);
                parmas.put("EMAIL",EMAILS);
                parmas.put("Closing_Balance",Closing_BalanceS);
                parmas.put("ITEM",ITEMS);
                parmas.put("GST",GSTS);
                parmas.put("CESS",CESSS);
                parmas.put("HSN",HSNS);
                parmas.put("SALE_RATE",SALE_RATES);
                parmas.put("PUR_RATE",PUR_RATES);
                parmas.put("QTY",QTYS);
                parmas.put("AMT",AMTS);
                parmas.put("GST_AMT",GST_AMTS);
                parmas.put("CESS_AMT",CESS_AMTS);
                parmas.put("TOTAL",TOTALS);

                return parmas;
            }
        };
        int socketTimeOut = 50000;// u can change this .. here it is 50 seconds

        RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        queue.add(stringRequest);


    }





    private void addView() {

        final View cricketerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.additem,null,false);

        final TextView itempartnoid1 = (TextView) cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.itempartnoid1);
        final TextView gstid1 = (TextView) cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.gstid1);
        final TextView cessid1 = (TextView) cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.cessid1);
        final TextView hsnid1 = (TextView) cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.hsnid1);
        final TextView SaleRate1 = (TextView) cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.SaleRate1);
        final TextView purrateid1 = (TextView) cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.purrateid1);
        final EditText qtyid1 = (EditText) cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.qtyid1);
        final TextView amtid1 = (TextView) cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.amtid1);
        final TextView gstamtid1 = (TextView) cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.gstamtid1);
        final TextView cessamtid1 = (TextView) cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.cessamtid1);
        final TextView totalid1 = (TextView) cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.totalid1);
        final TextView mrp = (TextView) cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.itemmrp1);



        Spinner itemspinner=(Spinner)cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.searchableSpinneritemid);
        ImageView imageClose = (ImageView)cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.image_remove);


        itemspinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,itemlist));
        itemspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "plz select number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    resulttext.setText(" ");
                }
                else {
                    final String snumber= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
//                    resulttext.setText(snumber);
                    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList=xlsxCon2.getSelectedEmp(snumber);
                    itempartnoid1.setText( myList.get(0).get(Constant2.ItemPartNo));
                    cessid1.setText( myList.get(0).get(Constant2.ItemCess));
                    hsnid1.setText( myList.get(0).get(Constant2.ItemHSN));
                    SaleRate1.setText( myList.get(0).get(Constant2.ItemSaleRate));
                    purrateid1.setText( myList.get(0).get(Constant2.ItemPurRate));
                    gstid1.setText( myList.get(0).get(Constant2.ItemGST));
                    mrp.setText( myList.get(0).get(Constant2.ItemMRP));
                    final String salerates=myList.get(0).get(Constant2.ItemSaleRate);
                    final String gst=myList.get(0).get(Constant2.ItemGST);
                    final String cess=myList.get(0).get(Constant2.ItemCess);





                    qtyid1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                            String  Value = qtyid1.getText().toString();

                            if(!Value.isEmpty())
                            {
//                                gst.replace("%","");
                                int gstint=Integer.parseInt(gst.replace("%",""));

//                                cess.replace("%","");
                                int cessint=Integer.parseInt(cess.replace("%",""));



                                int qty=Integer.parseInt(Value);
                                int salrt=Integer.parseInt(salerates);
                                int r=qty*salrt;
                                String result_amt=String.valueOf(r);
                                amtid1.setText(result_amt );

                                int gstamt=(gstint*r)/100;
                                String result_gstamt=String.valueOf(gstamt);
                                gstamtid1.setText(result_gstamt);
                                int cessamt=(cessint*r)/100;
                                String result_cessamt=String.valueOf(cessamt);
                                cessamtid1.setText(result_cessamt);

                                int total=r+gstamt+cessamt;
                                String total_amt=String.valueOf(total);
                                totalid1.setText(total_amt);
                            }
                            else {
                                amtid1.setText("0" );
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                        }
                    });
                    btnaddGSheet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            **addItemToSheet("","","","","","","","",snumber,
                                    myList.get(0).get(Constant2.ItemGST),myList.get(0).get(Constant2.ItemCess),myList.get(0).get(Constant2.ItemHSN),myList.get(0).get(Constant2.ItemSaleRate),
                                     myList.get(0).get(Constant2.ItemPurRate),qtyid1.getText().toString(),amtid1.getText().toString(),gstamtid1.getText().toString(),cessamtid1.getText().toString(),                            totalid1.getText().toString()
                            );**

                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        imageClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removeView(cricketerView);
            }
        });

        listViewLayout.addView(cricketerView);

    }

    private void removeView(View view){

        listViewLayout.removeView(view);

    }


}`enter code here`
```

Comment: plz modify this code only if it is possible thanks

Comment: Do yourself a favor and create one (or several) model classes that contain the fields like your `USER_NAME`, `Party`, `Address` etc. and use those models throughout your app, e.g. in your `myList`. Also, consider splitting your methods into smaller distinct methods. This will help you a lot in the long run.